# Conditional Sum Excluding Current Row

Tags: sql

I have the input table below. I want to create a column called **Desired** where, for each row (as if iterating through each row), the **Desired** value is the sum of **Measurement**s (excluding the Measurement value in the row being evaluated) where **Lower** <= (the Lower value in the row being evaluated) and **Upper** >= (the Upper value in the row being evaluated) and **ID2** = (ID2 in the row being evaluated). Right now, I only have data for **ID2** = 1, but in the future, we will add rows for **ID2** = 2, 3, 4, etc. I made up one row for **ID2** = 2 to have two distinct ID2s.

Just to try to explain my thinking, *for each row* in Input, do something like

```
SUM([MEASUREMENT] WHERE [ID2] = (ID2 in current row) 
    AND [LOWER] <= (LOWER value in current row)
    AND [UPPER] >= (UPPER value in current row)) - (MEASUREMENT in current row) AS [DESIRED]
```

Obviously that's not how it works but maybe it can clarify my thinking.

("Col value" in row being evaluated) is liked SelectedValue(Col) in DAX. (Sorry I have DAX on my mind.)

Seems like there should be a loop involved, but I'm hoping there is a non-loop solution.

The input table is ordered by [ID1], [ID2], [Value] DESC, [Lower]

In Excel, I was able to calculate the desired result like this (in cell G2):

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,B:B,B2,C:C,"<="&C2,E:E,">="&E2)-F2
```

How can I implement this in SQL?

Currently using Microsoft SQL Azure.

**Input**

| ID1 | ID2 | Lower | Value | Upper | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 38 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 25 | 25 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 25 | 25 | 50 | 62 |
| 2 | 1 | 7.5 | 17.5 | 25 | 43 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 7.5 | 7.5 | 44 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 7.5 | 7.5 | 44 |

**Expected**

| ID1 | ID2 | Lower | Value | Upper | Measurement | Desired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 38 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 25 | 25 | 20 | 38 |
| 2 | 1 | 25 | 25 | 50 | 62 | 38 |
| 2 | 1 | 7.5 | 17.5 | 25 | 43 | 58 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 7.5 | 7.5 | 44 | 58 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 7.5 | 7.5 | 44 | 0 |

Comment: Please explain the intended logic more detailed. What is a "current" row or "current" value for you? How are those rows sorted? Which rows should be compared? Please add both sample input data AND the expected result as tables in your question, explain in detail which rows should be compared following which sort and which logic.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I've updated my post. Let me know if I should add more clarifications.

Comment: I guess there is no really good solution for your idea in pure SQL. That's not what SQL is used for. Why do you need to do that in SQL if you already have calculated this column in Excel? Why not just import that table from Excel in your DB?

Comment: @flow maybe work on your description of the desired column a little bit more as it isn't clear how you are really wanting to calculate this. But window functions (analytical functions) with the proper ordering and some conditional aggregation will likely get you want you want.  Running Total in SQL is good to look up and learn from for this `SUM(col) OVER (ORDER BY otherCol)` .  If sequences can be broken you may need to familiarize yourself with Gap and Islands queries as well.  Biggest issue I see with data set is determining order as ID1/ID2 isn't unique to create a constant order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data has been stored in table named Numbers

```
WITH NUM AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID1, ID2 ORDER BY VALUE) AS RN
    FROM 
        NUMBERS A
)
SELECT 
    A.ID1, A.ID2, A.LOWER, A.VALUE,A.UPPER, A.MEASUREMENT,
    SUM(COALESCE(B.MEASUREMENT, 0)) AS DESIRED 
FROM 
    NUM A
LEFT JOIN 
    NUM B ON A.ID1 = B.ID1
          AND A.ID2 = B.ID2
          AND A.LOWER >= B.LOWER
          AND A.UPPER <= B.UPPER
          AND A.RN > B.RN 
GROUP BY 
    A.ID1, A.ID2, A.LOWER, A.VALUE,A.UPPER, A.MEASUREMENT
```

[Fiddle link with  query output](https://dbfiddle.uk/y4BVt32r)

Comment: It's not working for me. I tired to make some fixes on my end but the DESIRED column returns all 0s.

Comment: Added the measurement col now no error will be thrown, For me it   returns all the values as per your questions

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/y4BVt32r see this code works